# Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at generate

Tags: javascript

I'm learning to generate and remove one image at a time using DOM and I'm unable to understand this error. It works fine till I add the if statement. I've look thru similar post on stack overflow but still can't grasp it. My code as follows:

HTML

```
<div id="imageContainer">
         <!-- <img src="/image/bananas.jpg"> -->
</div>
```

Javascript

```
let images = [
       {
         image_name: 'bananas.jpg',
         number_of_items: 6,
       },
       {
         image_name: 'birthday candles.jpg',
         number_of_items: 7,
       },
       {
         image_name: 'blocks.jpg',
         number_of_items: 6,
       },
       {
         image_name: 'brushes.jpg',
         number_of_items: 7,
       }]

let generate = () => {
   let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
   let imageGenerated = images[randomNum].image_name;
   let imageContainer = document.getElementById("imageContainer");

   if (imageContainer.hasChildNodes()) {
      imageContainer.removeChild(imageContainer.firstElementChild);
   }

   let img = document.createElement("img");
   img.src = "image/" + imageGenerated;
   imageContainer.appendChild(img);   
};

let timer = () => {
   setInterval(generate, 3000);
};
```

Comment: [`hasChildNodes`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/hasChildNodes) returns `true` iff the parent has `childNodes`, not iff it has `children`. You’re attempting to remove the [`firstElementChild`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild), which may not exist (whereas the [`firstChild`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `hasChildNodes` checks for any type of node and the comment is a node.

To check for children use `element.children`, it returns an array-like object of all child elements.

```js
if (imageContainer.children.length) {
  imageContainer.removeChild(imageContainer.children[0];
}
```